# Data changes reflected wrong in parent window

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have the following requirements:

1. Show `TreeView` of items
2. Show Details of selected item in `TreeView`.
3. A dialog to edit the selected item.

I've implemented these requirements but the third doesn't do what it is supposed to do so I'm stuck.

What I want it to do :
The edit dialog should be able to edit an item. This isn't a `TreeViewItem` but an instance of one of my classes.

1. Save the edits - A button that will just close the dialog.
2. Discard the edits - A button to reset the fields changed in the item and close dialog.

The second requirement does not work. If I edit a field and hit Cancel, the item details panel still shows the edits. I have debugged but I find that the underlying item is unchanged - however the item is displayed with the changed values.

Code:

1. Item class (Category)

   ```
   public class Category
   {
       public virtual int Id { get; set; }
       public virtual string Name { get; set; }
       public virtual string Description { get; set; }
       public virtual Unit Unit { get; set; }
       public virtual List<Category> ChildCategories { get; set; }
       public virtual Category ParentCategory { get; set; }
       public virtual bool IsMainCategory { get; set; }

       public Category()
       {
           ChildCategories = new List<Category>();
       }

       public virtual void AddChild(Category child)
       {
           ChildCategories.Add(child);
           child.ParentCategory = this;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Item (Category) Details are shown in a label:

   ```
   <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Category}">
       <Grid>
           <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
               <ColumnDefinition Width="4*" SharedSizeGroup="a" />
               <ColumnDefinition Width="6*" SharedSizeGroup="b" />
           </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
           <Grid.RowDefinitions>
               <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
               <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
           </Grid.RowDefinitions>

           <TextBlock Text="Name" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Padding="5"/>
           <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Padding="5"/>
           <TextBlock Text="Description" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Padding="5"/>
           <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Description}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Padding="5"/>
       </Grid>
   </DataTemplate>
   ```
3. Event handler for Edit item in Main Window :

   ```
   private void EditCategory(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
       Category ctg = _tree.SelectedItem as Category;
       if (ctg != null)
       {
           CategoryDefineWindow cdw = new CategoryDefineWindow();
           cdw.CategoryObject = ctg;
           cdw.ShowDialog();
       }
   }
   ```
4. Item editor window xaml:

   ```
   <Window x:Class="BSRCat.View.CategoryDefineWindow"
       xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
       Height="150" Width="500">
   <Grid>
       <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
           <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" SharedSizeGroup="a" />
           <ColumnDefinition Width="7*" SharedSizeGroup="b" />
       </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
       <Grid.RowDefinitions>
           <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
           <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
           <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
       </Grid.RowDefinitions>

       <TextBlock Text="Name" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Padding="5"/>
       <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=CategoryObject.Name, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Padding="5"/>
       <TextBlock Text="Description" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Padding="5"/>
       <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=CategoryObject.Description, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Padding="5"/>

       <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
           <Button Content="Ok" Margin="5" Height="20" Width="30" Click="Confirmed"/>
           <Button Content="Cancel" Margin="5" Height="20" Width="50" Click="Cancelled"/>
       </StackPanel>
   </Grid>
   </Window>
   ```
5. Item editor window code behind :

   ```
   public partial class CategoryDefineWindow : Window
   {
       public Category CategoryObject 
       {
           get
           {
           return _category;
           }
           set
           {
               _category = value;
               _initial = new Category() { Name = value.Name, Description = value.Description     };
           }
       }

       private Category _category;
       private Category _initial;

       public CategoryDefineWindow()
       {
           InitializeComponent();
       }

       private void Confirmed(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
       {
           Close();
       }

       private void Cancelled(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
       {
           _category.Name = _initial.Name;
           _category.Description = _initial.Description;
           Close();
       }
   }
   ```

I've debugged the `CategoryDefineWindow.Cancelled` method and the `_category` object is reset correctly. I can't find where it goes wrong.

Comment: How does the details panel get the updated values in the first place? Does the Category class implement INotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: Just a side note: I'd recommend to implement the Interface ICloneable and in its Clone Method use the method object.MemberwiseClone(). This way you don't need all this attribute copying stuff, which is cumbersome to implement when the number of attributes you need to copy increases ..

Comment: @Jefim : I bound the `TreeView.SelectedItem` to the `Content` property of the label. With the `DataTemplate` defined, I get the details panel in that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Category class should be implemented INotifyPropertyChanged interface. WPF will be notified once the value of properties have changed.

```
   public class Category : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _Name;
    private string _Description;

    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _Name;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_Name == value)
                return;

            _Name = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }

    public virtual string Description
    {
        get
        {
            return _Description;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_Description == value)
                return;

            _Description = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Description");
        }
    }
    public virtual Unit Unit { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Category> ChildCategories { get; set; }
    public virtual Category ParentCategory { get; set; }
    public virtual bool IsMainCategory { get; set; }

    public Category()
    {
        ChildCategories = new List<Category>();
    }

    public virtual void AddChild(Category child)
    {
        ChildCategories.Add(child);
        child.ParentCategory = this;
    }

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```